# How to pass experimental chrome options in puppeteer

Tags: python, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer

I have an application written in python/[selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) which set some experimental options on the [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US',
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.default_directory': '/dev/null',
        'automatic_downloads': 2,
        'download_restrictions': 3,
        'notifications': 2,
        'media_stream': 2,
        'media_stream_mic': 2,
        'media_stream_camera': 2,
        'durable_storage': 2,
        'plugins': 2,
        'popups': 2,
        'site_engagement': 2,
        'midi_sysex': 2,
        'mouselock': 2,
        'geolocation': 2,
    }
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

I need to port the same application to node/[puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) but I am not sure how to pass the experimental options to `puppeteer/chromium`:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const options = {
        headless: true,
        args: [
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--lang=en',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-browser-side-navigation',
            '--mute-audio',
        ],
    };

    // experimental options ??

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

})();
```

Is it possible to pass Chrome experimental options to `puppeteer`?

Answer (score 2):

I.) Normally you should be able to set any experimental features among the `args` if you are able to position them between the `--flag-switches-begin` and `--flag-switches-end` flags and you give them in the following format: *Pascal case option names, separated by a single comma without a space.*
E.g. if you want to set `enable-nacl` and `network-service`:

```
--enable-features=EnableNacl,NetworkService
```

Experimental features can be checked here: [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) if they are indeed enabled.

The *Command Line* of Chrome/Chromium can be checked here: [chrome://version](http://chrome://version/) to see if the flags are added at the launch.

---

II.) For me this solution haven't worked (it doesn't mean it wouldn't work for you, it worths a try). So I use a workaround of creating a Chrome profile (Experimental Profile 1) where I enable [manually](http://chrome://flags.) the experimantal flags and then using this profile with puppeteer (`--user-data-dir=` and `--profile-directory=` are required):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      // '--enable-features=EnableNacl,NetworkService',
      '--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user.name\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\User Data',
      '--profile-directory=Experimental Profile 1'
    ]
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('chrome://flags/#enable-nacl')
}
fn()
```

The example above is for Windows, see more platforms and more info [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

*Note:* You can retrieve executable and profile paths on the [chrome://version](http://chrome://version) page.

*Note 2:* The example above can be run only with `headless: false` as headless mode cannot visit invalid URLs like *chrome://flags/#enable-nacl* but the user profile should work. If it isn't then there is a known chromium bug related to relative path of data dir which be solved with `path.resolve`, e.g.:

```js
const path = require('path')
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: [`--user-data-dir=${path.resolve(__dirname, 'User Data') }`] })
```

[[source]](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/921#issuecomment-616714656)

---

### Edit

Actually the options you want to set are only called *experimental options* by [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) but available as chrome policies at [chrome://policy](http://chrome://policy/) page. Make sure you've set *Show policies with no value set* to see them.

But as far as I see it doesn't provide a simple solution (e.g. in case of Windows you are limited to set it via registry). After searching on GitHub I've found in [this discussion](http://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1693) that `chrome_options.add_experimental_option` is not implemented in puppeteer as in ChromeDriver.
But in [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra) there is a dedicated plugin for this, called: [user-preferences](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences).

**For example:**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')({ userPrefs: {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false
  }
}}))
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
```

Reference of pref names and their access: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the first way didn't work for me either and can't go with the second since I need headless automation

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion with the 2nd solution, I think it can work even with headless mode: I meant my specific example script cannot be run headless, but if you are using a full (not relative) `--user-data-dir` path the experimental features can be set on a headless chrome as well. It may worths a try as well.

Comment: Ok I am trying to set some experimental flags on a new Chrome profile...the problem is in chrome://flags I can't find any of the experimental option I need to set, like `download_restrictions` or `prompt_for_download`. Do you have any idea where I can find them and save in the profile so I can then try to load the profile in `puppeteer`?

Comment: Actually these two are not experimental options but chrome policies and available at _chrome://policy/_ page. Make sure you've set _ Show policies with no value set_ to see them. FYI: `prompt_for_download` is called now _PromptForDownloadLocation_.

Comment: _Update:_ But as far as I see it doesn't provide a simple solution (e.g. in case of Windows you are limited to set it via registry). After searching on GitHub I've found the `chrome_options.add_experimental_option` is not implemented in puppeteer as in ChromeDriver: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1693 but in [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra) there is a dedicated plugin for this, called: [user-preferences](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences). I will update my answer with this.

Comment: It seems that the plugin `user-preferences` does not support headless chrome unfortunately. I got this warning:
```Warning: Plugin 'user-preferences' is not supported in headless mode.```

Comment: this topic seems to be cursed If you'd find the solution later on: make sure to post it here as an answer. I have already become obsessed with it, as it should be possible to use headless chrome with user prefrences and even with experimental feature flags.

Comment: Sure! It seems weird that `puppeteer` which is specifically for Chrome/Chromium does not support user preferences while `Selenium` with Chrome driver does