# Puppeteer can't load extension in headless

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I'm trying to load an extension to chrome with puppeteer, works in headless:false, but it doesn't with headless: true. Can it be done?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: '//usr//bin//google-chrome',
        args: [
            '--start-maximized',
            `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
            `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
            `--window-size=1920,1080`,
          ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only run extensions in the `headless:true` mode when, per the [puppeteer docs](https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions) they specifically state:

> "Extensions in Chrome/Chromium currently only work in non-headless
> mode and experimental Chrome headless mode."

See this question: [How to pass experimental chrome options in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62863720/9554981)

To run in headless, you will need to use `puppeteer-extra` with the plugin `user-preferences`. This will enable the ability to use experimental chrome headless by allowing you to set the flag `chrome_options.add_experimental_option` when puppeteer starts.